# Javascript read a txt file onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched through the net but i only get the ones with `<input type="file">`. I also got what I want but for some reason, it only work when I use netbeans and click the run project button. What i need is something that would work even without running netbeans.

Comment: Red up on how to use ajax

Comment: Javascript is client-side. You can't read from filesystem.

Comment: So theres no way i can do that?

Comment: Yes you can't, you have to do an AJAX call to the server giving you the file data. JQuery have a very simple API for doing that, see @Ryan's answer. Just know that the load of the file is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").load("file.txt");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I found two answers also but this is much simpler and easier to understand.